# How do I make the borders of a textbox circular using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am making an email textfield and would love for the edges of the textbox to be circular. I have no clue on how to go about it. Any help will be beneficial.

Comment: Can you include a  reference image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Flutter Form Builder package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder), you can define it in decoration -> border ->  OutlineInputBorder -> borderRadius. You can play with different options. Example with borderRadius 20 below:

```
       FormBuilderTextField(
          name: 'email',
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more like you need to use [`OutlineInputBorder()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlineInputBorder-class.html).

```dart
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)  
      ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(), // or just OutlineInputBorder()
  ),
),
```